# How to do a transaction simulation?

Tags: go-ethereum, simulation

Alchemy(https://www.alchemy.com/transaction-simulation), Blocknative(https://www.blocknative.com/simulation-platform), flashbots(*eth_callbundle, mev_simbundle*), they all have apis to simulate transaction or bundle.
First thing I would like to know, what is the principle of simulating a trade? I have built my own ethereum node, is it possible to simulate transaction on my node as well?
Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

A simulation could be useful to know the outcome. In security are used by white hats to simulate attacks without making them public.

Ganache has a 'fork' feature that allows doing simulations from an existing blockchain.